# How to get outlook email Subject using add-in express

Tags: c#, outlook, addin-express

I am new to Add-In express outlook development. I am working with sample project getting email subject when select the email and clicking the button get the subject details in the popup window.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to dev.office.com, you'll find thousands of examples there

Comment: Thanks @PedroG.Dias for your answer. I want know it using Add-In express. In there i cant find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection. Loop through all items in that collection and read the `MailItem.Subject` property.